# How to obtain city name from coordinates using Google maps

Tags: php, geocoding

I'm using the following code, but I cannot get it working. It should take the coordinates and return a city name

```
<?php
function getAddress($lat, $lon) {
    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".
    $lat.",".$lon."&sensor=false";
    $json = @file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($json);
    $status = $data->status;
    $address = '';
    if($status == "OK"){
        foreach($data->results[0]->address_components as $address_component) {
            if(in_array('street_number', $address_component->types)) {
                $street_number = $address_component->long_name;
            }
            if(in_array('route', $address_component->types)) {
                 $route = $address_component->long_name;
            }
        }
    }
    return $street_number." ".$route;
}

echo getAddress(-1.566120,53.824);
```

However, it returns a blank white page. What am I doing wrong?
Please help.

-- UPDATED CODE --
*Simplified a little*..

```
 <?php
    
        $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44,44&key=<your-key-here>&sensor=false";
        $json = @file_get_contents($url);
        $data = json_decode($json);
        $status = $data->status;
        $address = '';
        if($status == "OK"){
            foreach($data->results[0]->address_components as $address_component) {
                if(in_array('street_number', $address_component->types)) {
                    $street_number = $address_component->long_name;
                }
                if(in_array('route', $address_component->types)) {
                     $route = $address_component->long_name;
                }
            }
        }
        echo $street_number." ".$route;
    
    ?>
```

Still looking for awnsers :)

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps API requires an API key passed in the URL, as shown in this example below.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Please note the above URL is HTTPS, not HTTP. HTTP no longer works with the Google APIs.

As @catcon said, you need to enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project.

However, so that you don't get a blank page, I would recommend the following code changes.

Change this

```
...
$json = @file_get_contents($url);
...
```

to this

```
...
$json = @file_get_contents($url);
if ($json['status'] != 'OK') {
  return $json;
}
...
```

This will allow you to see the result of the API call if it fails.

Comment: @Mandaus 1) Do not post your API key here, please delete it asap 2) you should check for error when request to google API. When I try to request with your key, Google return the message "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project"

Comment: Firstly, I would remove your API key from the comment for security reasons.
Secondly, after trying this, I have the answer. You need to use HTTPS to access the Google APIs.

Comment: sucks that it isnt free

Comment: I changed the "http://" to "https://", and accessed my host via an HTTPS connection. still white page. I think I need to pay Google for the benefit, which sucks.

Comment: @Mandaus: Google Map Api is free as long as you don't go over the limit, check https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing

Comment: Hi. I get the following message:
`'{ "error_message" : "Requests to this API must be over SSL. Load the API with \"https://\" instead of \"http://\".", "results" : [], "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" }'`


and, when I change to https i get: 
`{ "error_message" : "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started", "results" : [], "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" }'`

Comment: Exactly. The first error message is telling you you need to use HTTPS, and the second is saying you must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project, both as described in my answer. Thanks, @catcon for the reminder about enabling Billing.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks guys :P